# Angular 6 : HTTP Interceptor two calls for http request

Tags: angular, http, angular-http-interceptors

I have implemented interceptors in angular 6 application. The issue I am facing is that for every http cal, be it get or post. It is sending two request. Why is that happening.

Comment: Is it a different domain you are making a request to? If so the first is an options call not a get call.

Comment: Else please put the code.

Comment: Who did -1 to this post. Don`t be unnecessarily aggressive.

Comment: You should include the requests you are seeing in the web inspector's network tab in your post.

Comment: @Maddy is it a different domain or same domain.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very similar to what i was seeing in my own application and this was prior to Angular 6, so I do not think this behavior is specific to Angular 6.

I was using the Angular JWT module that lives on GitHub when i experienced seeing a double set of requests being sent to the server, and reported this as a potential bug, but after some discussion, it seems the behavior that i was seeing was normal.

Please see this link for the full discussion and answer to see if it mirrors what you described:
[Angular, Seeing 2 requests sent to server](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/407)